# CREATE ANY VIEW SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, privileges, sql-view

I’ve been reading about privileges and came across `GRANT CREATE ANY VIEW TO`. What does the CREATE ANY VIEW TO actually do? Does it just create a view to a user?

Comment: From [here:](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_8004.htm#SQLRF01504) *"To create a view in your own schema, you must have the CREATE VIEW system privilege. To create a view in another user's schema, you must have the CREATE ANY VIEW system privilege."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the privilege is actually `CREATE ANY VIEW`, not `CREATE ANY VIEW TO`.

First of all, this does not *create a view*. A privilege is *a right* to perform a specific type of operation (or a group of them), to access an object (or a group of them), and so on. You give (*grant*) a privilege to a user (*grantee*) with a command like :

```
GRANT <privilege> TO <user>
```

The `CREATE ANY VIEW` privilege allows the grantee to create a view in any schema. By opposition, the `CREATE VIEW` priviliege allows a user to create views only in its own  schema.

From [the Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_8004.htm#SQLRF01504) :

> To create a view in your own schema, you must have the `CREATE VIEW` system privilege. To create a view in another user's schema, you must have the `CREATE ANY VIEW` system privilege